# iAP work in Sandbox but not in 'Pending Developer Release' version

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Our app has passed review, and is pending developer release. I've downloaded a copy using a promo code, but none of our in App purchases work (they work fine using a sandbox account created in iTunes Connect however). iAP are approved and cleared for sale in iTunes Connect.

They are reporting this error in the console on attempted purchase:

```
Nov 22 20:58:34 iOS-8-tester-takp accountsd[3148] <Warning>: AIDA Notification plugin running
Nov 22 20:58:36 iOS-8-tester-takp backupd[3317] <Warning>: INFO: Account changed (enabled=1, accountID=REDACTED)
Nov 22 20:58:49 iOS-8-tester-takp backupd[3318] <Warning>: INFO: Account changed (enabled=1, accountID=REDACTED)
Nov 22 20:58:49 iOS-8-tester-takp itunesstored[78] <Warning>: Could not load library [21]
Nov 22 20:58:51 iOS-8-tester-takp accountsd[3148] <Warning>: [Warning] Unhandled server key: alert
Nov 22 20:58:52 iOS-8-tester-takp identityservicesd[42] <Warning>: [Warning] IDS access warning: Allowing wildcard access for service: com.apple.private.alloy.bulletinboard entitlement: com.apple.private.ids.registration client: com.apple.Accounts:accountsd:3148 entitlements: {
         "com.apple.private.ids.messaging" =     (
             "com.apple.private.alloy.accountssync"
         );
         "com.apple.private.ids.messaging.high-priority" =     (
             "com.apple.private.alloy.accountssync"
         );
         "com.apple.private.ids.registration" = 1;
     }
```

Perhaps this is a server error - but it's making me really nervous with our release coming up. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a server error. It fixed itself 3 or 4 days after moving to 'Pending Developer Release' and operates as expected now, with no change in the application's code.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Wonder if it takes a longer time if I keep it at this status instead of releasing it. Any idea? Do you remember if you've had an expired paid contract too?